# Entities used by ORM in combination with CodeContracts - ensure invariants

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, code-contracts

I am currently in the process of adding CodeContracts to my existing code base.
One thing that proves difficult is the usage of entities that are hydrated by NHibernate.

Assume this simple class:

```
public class Post
{
    private Blog _blog;

    [Obsolete("Required by NHibernate")]
    protected Post() { }

    public Post(Blog blog)
    {
        Contract.Requires(blog != null);
        _blog = blog;
    }

    public Blog Blog
    {
        get
        {
            Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Blog>() != null);
            return _blog;
        }
        set
        {
            Contract.Requires(value != null);
            _blog = value;
        }
    }

    [ContractInvariantMethod]
    private void Invariants()
    {
        Contract.Invariant(_blog != null);
    }
}
```

This class tries to protect the invariant `_blog != null`. However, it currently fails, because I easily could create an instance of `Post` by deriving from it and using the protected constructor. In that case `_blog` would be `null`.
I am trying to change my code-base in a way that the invariants are indeed protected.

The protected constructor is at first sight needed by NHibernate to be able to create new instances, but there is [a way around this requirement](http://kozmic.net/2011/03/20/working-with-nhibernate-without-default-constructors/).
That approach basically uses [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx). The important point is, that this method doesn't run any constructors.
I could use this approach and it would allow me to get rid of the protected constructor. The static checker of CodeContracts would now be happy and not report any more violations, but as soon as NHibernate tries to hydrate such entities it will generate "invariant failed" exceptions, because it tries to set one property after the other and every property setter executes code that verifies the invariants.

So, to make all this work, I will have to ensure that the entities are instantiated via their public constructor.

But how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion with tucaz, I came up with the following, in its core rather simple solution:

The heart of this solution is the class `NHibernateActivator`. It has two important purposes:

1. Create an instance of an object without invoking its constructors. It uses [`FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx) for this.
2. Prevent the triggering of "invariant failed" exceptions while NHibernate hydrates the instance. This is a two-step task: Disable invariant checking before NHibernate starts hydrating and re-enable invariant checking after NHibernate is done.
   The first part can be performed directly after the instance has been created.
   The second part is using the interface `IPostLoadEventListener`.

The class itself is pretty simple:

```
public class NHibernateActivator : INHibernateActivator, IPostLoadEventListener
{
    public bool CanInstantiate(Type type)
    {
        return !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsInterface &&
               !type.IsGenericTypeDefinition && !type.IsSealed;
    }

    public object Instantiate(Type type)
    {
        var instance = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(type);
        instance.DisableInvariantEvaluation();
        return instance;
    }

    public void OnPostLoad(PostLoadEvent @event)
    {
        if (@event != null && @event.Entity != null)
            @event.Entity.EnableInvariantEvaluation(true);
    }
}
```

`DisableInvariantEvaluation` and `EnableInvariantEvaluation` are currently extension methods that use reflection to set a protected field. This field prevents invariants from being checked. Furthermore `EnableInvariantEvaluation` will execute the method that checks the invariants if it gets passed `true`:

```
public static class CodeContractsExtensions
{
    public static void DisableInvariantEvaluation(this object entity)
    {
        var evaluatingInvariantField = entity.GetType()
                                             .GetField(
                                                 "$evaluatingInvariant$", 
                                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                                 BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (evaluatingInvariantField == null)
            return;
        evaluatingInvariantField.SetValue(entity, true);
    }

    public static void EnableInvariantEvaluation(this object entity,
                                                 bool evaluateNow)
    {
        var evaluatingInvariantField = entity.GetType()
                                             .GetField(
                                                 "$evaluatingInvariant$", 
                                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                                 BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (evaluatingInvariantField == null)
            return;
        evaluatingInvariantField.SetValue(entity, false);

        if (!evaluateNow)
            return;
        var invariantMethod = entity.GetType()
                                    .GetMethod("$InvariantMethod$",
                                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                               BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (invariantMethod == null)
            return;
        invariantMethod.Invoke(entity, new object[0]);
    }
}
```

The rest is NHibernate plumbing:

1. We need to implement an interceptor that uses our activator.
2. We need to implement an reflection optimizer that returns our implementation of `IInstantiationOptimizer`. This implementation in turn again uses our activator.
3. We need to implement a proxy factory that uses our activator.
4. We need to implement `IProxyFactoryFactory` to return our custom proxy factory.
5. We need to create a custom proxy validator that doesn't care whether the type has a default constructor.
6. We need to implement a bytecode provider that returns our reflection optimizer and proxy-factory factory.
7. NHibernateActivator needs to be registered as a listener using `config.AppendListeners(ListenerType.PostLoad, ...);` in `ExposeConfiguration` of Fluent NHibernate.
8. Our custom bytecode provider needs to be registered using `Environment.BytecodeProvider`.
9. Our custom interceptor needs to be registered using `config.Interceptor = ...;`.

I will update this answer when I had the chance to create a coherent package out of all this and put it on github.
Furthermore, I want to get rid of the reflection and create a proxy type instead that can directly access the protected CodeContract members.

For reference, the following blog posts where helpful in implementing the several NHibernate interfaces:

- http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2012/06/19/implementing-an-interceptor-using-nhibernate-s-built-in-dynamic-proxy-generator.aspx
- http://kozmic.net/2011/03/20/working-with-nhibernate-without-default-constructors/

---

Unfortunately, this currently fails for entities with composite keys, because the reflection optimizer is not used for them. This is actually a bug in NHibernate and I reported it [here](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3410).

Comment: Although it uses a lot of complex extension points and hidden methods its a simple solution. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Daniel, if I'm not mistaken (it's been a while since I worked with NH) you can have a private constructor and he still should be fine creating your object.

Aside from that, why do you need to be a 100% sure? Is it a requirement in some way or you are just trying to covering all the bases?

I ask that because depending on the requirement we could come with another way of achieving it.

What you COULD do right now to provide that extra protection is wire up an IInterceptor class to make sure that after the load your class is still valid.

I guess that the bottom line is if someone want's to mess up with your domain and classes they WILL do it no matter what you do. The effort to prevent all that stuff doesn't pay off in most cases.

**Edit after clarification**

If you use your objects to write to the database and you contracts are working you can safely assume that the data will be written correctly and therefore loaded correctly if no one tampers with the database.

If you do change the database manually you should either stop doing it and use your domain to do that (that's where the validation logic is) or test the database changing process.

Still, if you really need that you can still hook up a IInterceptor that will validate your entity after the load, but I don't think you fix a water flooding coming from the street by making sure your house pipe is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I am aware, a private constructor never was an option - at least not if you didn't want to create those interceptor classes. The purpose is not to defend against malicious users. The purpose is to fail fast in case of a bug in code or data. If the data in the database doesn't conform to the contract - maybe because the latest database update didn't go through properly? - I want to get an exception as soon as NHibernate tries to hydrate such an object.

Comment: Thanks. I don't agree with the update though. There are two systems in place here: The database and the application. Both protect their boundaries. The database via FKs, PKs, unique indexes etc. And the application via code contracts. It's not about validation, really. It's about having a valid object. One of the purposes of Code Contracts is to fail fast. And that's what I want to do. As I said before, no one needs to "tamper" with anything for a contract to break. A small bug in the mapping is all that's needed.

Comment: And I rather have a contract violation exception "requires InvoiceNumber != null" when the entity is constructed than a random `NullReferenceException` somewhere in my code.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is very hard and personally I've never seen a good solution for it before. I've been where you are and I when the answer started to get as complex as it's getting I realized it wasn't worth it. ORM's (at least NH) are not compatible to this kind of validation out of the box. What I ended up doing is having a IsValid method and calling that before saving and after loading the entity. You could add it as part of a IEntityValidator interface and intercept NH after it loads calling IsValid method.

Comment: Another option I've come up with, but with a not trivial implementation would be to have a Builder class to build your entities and somehow tell NHibernate to rehydrate them using it. At the end making sure that one instance is valid is only possible when you are sure the validation point will be called and that doesn't happen when you have variants like that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I realize it's hard. Even more so, because I don't want to add any support for this to my entities. But I think it actually should be possible, because all classes that contain contracts and invariants already contain a method that makes sure the invariants are satisfied. Maybe calling this method is the solution. That would be an implementation of option 3 from my question.

Comment: About the Builder: Yeah, I though about that, too, but it would require way too much manual effort. For every entity I would have to write a corresponding builder.

Comment: If such method is available, use the interceptor to call it after NHibernate loads your entity. That should do the trick.

Comment: Problem is, it's not *easily* available, because it's automatically generated by the CodeContracts assembly rewriter and protected. I will have to use reflection to be able to call it. But yes, I guess that's the way to go.

Comment: Do it and release as a NHibernate/CC plugin :)

Comment: Hm, it's even harder than I thought. Invariants are checked at the end of every member. That makes it impossible to use my entities the way they are, because the first property NHibernate tries to set will result in an "invariant failed" exception, because the invariants for the fields of the other properties are false, because they haven't been set yet. That means that the only option left is #1 from my question. The public constructor needs to be used. To be able to do that, we are back at the builder, I guess.

Comment: Furthermore, lazy properties are a problem, too. As soon as the contract is more advanced than a not `null` check it would evaluate the lazy properties and fetch the data.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess that you are going towards the complexity where making it work isn't worth it.

Comment: I guess it would be possible: I can tell the CodeContracts engine at runtime that certain violations should be ignored, i.e. while NH populates the properties. But it feels pretty hacky, because I haven't found a real entry point in NH after the loading finished, to tell Code Contracts to stop ignoring violations and I can't ignore Contract violations for a certain instance. Only for a certain type, making it pretty vulnerable in multi-threading environments. But I haven't yet given up completely... ;)

Comment: I think I found a possible solution. Please see my answer, if you are interested.