# Why doesnt the .Net framework use Guard class (or equivalent) for method arguments

Tags: c#, .net

if one takes a look at the decompiled source of the .net framework code most of the APIs have checks like these

```
if (source == null)
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
```

on the method arguments instead of using a more generic class like

```
Guard.IsNotNull(source);
```

Is there a reason behind doing this explicilty every time or is this just legacy code that is been around since the framework was developed and the newer classes are moving towards this or are there any inherent advantages of having explicit checks? One reason that I could think off is probably to avoid overloading the stack with function pointers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Adding to Matthews answer:

Your proposed syntax of `Guard.IsNotNull(source);` is not directly equivalent to the first code snippet. It only passes the *value* of the parameter but not its name, so the thrown exception can't report the name of the offending parameter. It just knows that *one* of the parameters is `null`.

You could use expression trees - like so: `Guard.IsNotNull(() => source);` - but analyzing this expression tree has a rather large performance impact at *runtime*, so this isn't an option either.

Your proposed syntax could only be used in conjunction with a static weaver. That's basically a post-compiler that changes the generated IL. That's the approach Code Contracts are using. But this comes with its own cost, namely:

1. That static weaver needs to be written by someone in the first place
2. It increases build time
3. The weaver also needs to patch the debug symbols
4. It causes all sorts of problems with Edit and Continue

Comment: In fairness, I've found Edit and Continue to be flakey at the best of times anyway; I rarely if ever use it (and it doesn't work with 64-bit programs anyway).

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Indeed. It is just the smallest of the costs. I added the biggest cost - I was missing that.

Answer (score 11):

Nowadays we can do this with [`Code Contracts`](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) so we can use:

```
Contract.Requires(source != null);
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<MyType>() != null);
```

and so on, but currently we can only do this in our own code because this isn't built in to the CLR yet (it's a separate download).

The Code Contracts classes themselves have been a part of .Net since version 4, but by themselves they don't generate any checking code. To do that we need the code contracts rewriter which will be called by the C# compiler when generating your code. That's the thing that needs a separate download.

So yes we have better ways to do this now, but it hasn't been released as part of the CLR (yet) and so the CLR is currently using what you think of as a "legacy" approach.

It's certainly nothing to do with "overloading the stack with function pointers".

Even with Code Contracts, we are still doing a check of course. There's no IL command that I know of that checks an argument for null and throws if it is, so such work has to be done using several IL instructions (in all CLR languages). However, the Code Contracts code rewriter does generate inline code to check the Code Contract's predicate (e.g. `value != null`) rather than calling a method to do so, so it is very efficient.

Comment: +1. Although I have used CodeContract before in the project, for now they seem to be more trouble than it's worth sometimes, especially when you're doing ClickOnce - unless you disable it completely, the rewriter can mess up the hashes. But I'm waiting to see if they can push it a little bit more forward... :)

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor We've been using Code Contracts with our Click Once apps (of which we have many) for more than a year with no problems... We are using them very extensively. The main problem is that it slows down compile times, but we haven't had other issues (except with the debugger not showing locals in methods with `yield` and some spurious Code Analysis warnings, but those bugs have been fixed now). Since I was a big Eiffel fan back in the early 90s, I have welcomed Code Contracts. :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Just to clarify: The `Contract` classes are part of the .NET framework since .NET 4. You "only" need to download the VS addin that contains the static weaver.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: BTW: What do you mean when you say *"Even with Code Contracts, we are still doing an explicit check."*? Are you saying you are doing a `null` check in addition to the `Contract.Requires`?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Thanks, yes that's what I meant - you need the thing that actually re-writes the code to use the Code Contracts. What I meant by *doing an explicit check* is that the Code Contracts rewriter emits inline code to check the predicate. It doesn't make a function call to do so. I updated my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: You say you are using CC extensivly. Are you also using the static checker or just the runtime checker?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth We use the static checker occasionally - it's too slow to use all the time. Also it generates a lot of warnings and it's quite a pain to change all the code (especially legacy code) to remove all the warnings, so we tend to use it mostly on newer code. But we really do find bugs with the static checker!

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I hope it's not too OT here, but: I tried to use CC on a rather large application myself and while I prefer the CC syntax over the legacy if-throw syntax, I see the real value in the static checker. Using the static checker only makes sense of you try to eliminate all warnings, and that's what I tried. I actually came quite far, however, I came across a problem I was unable to solve: [Entities used by an ORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110837/entities-used-by-orm-in-combination-with-codecontracts-ensure-invariants). You can't use invariants on them, because (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) they are not initialized with a constructor but by setting the properties or fields via reflection. Did you find a solution for this? Or are you just treating entities as second-class citizens and liter your code with calls to `Contract.Assume` whenever using a property of an entity?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I'm afraid we do have quite a few Contract.Assumes() (I don't really have a big problem with that, I used to use `ASSERT()` a lot in my old C++ programs back in the day, and it's pretty much the same thing). But like you, I do far prefer to get rid of the warnings using proper code contracts but often it just isn't possible without Contract.Assume(), like you say.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I found the impact on the compile performance was acceptable for small libraries but as soon as the solution contains >5 projects each with its own contracts, cc (even without static checking) really slows down the compiler

Comment: @vc74 I found it adds about 3-4 seconds overhead per project (based on my timings).

Comment: @MatthewWatson same here although I've got a decent configuration... unfortunately it's not acceptable for day to day compilation

Comment: In my project, with the static checker enabled, it added an overhead of minutes - and I am not talking about 2 or 3 - to a build that normally runs in some 20 seconds on a machine with SSD, 12 GB of RAM and a quad core CPU. A few seconds would have been really great.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yep the static checker is extremely slow - it's doing a lot of work I guess. That's why we only run the static checker occasionally.

Answer (score 5):

There's no Guard class in the .NET framework so your proposed alternative is not feasible.  Later additions to the framework do use code contracts, but rather sparingly.  Not every .NET programmer at Microsoft seems that convinced that contracts are that useful, I do share the sentiment.

You are otherwise seeing the way Microsoft works.  Code in the .NET framework is contributed by *lots* of small teams within the company.  A typical team size is about 10 programmers.  Otherwise a nod to what everybody in software dev business knows, large teams don't work.  There's a critical mass where the amount of time spent on getting everybody to communicate starts to overwhelm the amount of time that can be spent on actually getting code produced.

Such teams are also constantly created and disbanded.  Lots of parts of the framework no longer have an active team that maintains it.  Typically just one guy that still knows the internals well enough to provide critical security updates and, maybe, bug fixes when necessary.  The code that such a disbanded team wrote is very much in maintenance mode, changes are only made when absolutely necessary.  Not just because there's no benefit to making minor stylistic changes but to reduce the odds that breaking changes are unknowingly added.

Which is a liability for the .NET framework, there are plenty of internals that have a knack for becoming externally visible, even if that code lives inside private methods.  Like exceptions.  And programmers using Reflection to hack around framework limitations.  And the really subtle stuff, a great example is the bug in an email app widely used inside Microsoft, written by an intern.  Which crashed and left everybody without email when they updated their machine from .NET 1.1 to .NET 2.0.  The bug in that email app was a latent threading race that never triggered when running with .NET 1.1.  But became visible by a very slight change in the timing of .NET 2.0 framework code.

Answer (score 3):

It might not be a part of .NET Framework but Microsoft developers seem to be embracing the concept (notice the use of JetBrains annotations instead of Code Contracts as well):

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/master/src/Shared/Check.cs

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Open Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using JetBrains.Annotations;

namespace Microsoft.Data.Entity.Utilities
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    internal static class Check
    {
        [ContractAnnotation("value:null => halt")]
        public static T NotNull<T>([NoEnumeration] T value, [InvokerParameterName] [NotNull] string parameterName)
        {
            NotEmpty(parameterName, "parameterName");

            if (ReferenceEquals(value, null))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(parameterName);
            }

            return value;
        }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of, is that if you have a `Guard` class, then in the exception stacktrace, it will look as if the problem is in `Guard` when it's actually in the method that called `Guard`. You could get around this by catching and rethrowing, but then you've got boilerplate in your production code again.

Comment: wont your exception be throwing that this argument is null which is what we want.. and the stack trace will show the callee method too.

Comment: The stack trace will show the callee method, but it's not immediately obvious in which method the problem occurred.

Comment: You can decorate the methods of your Guard class with [DebuggerHiddenAttribute] which means the debugger won't stop in the Guard class, but back in the caller.